# Join two columns from one table to one column from another

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use my home_team and away_team fixture_id's to get their name values from a different table.

This works to get the name value of home_team

```
SELECT * FROM fixtures JOIN teams ON fixtures.home_teamID = teams.TeamID
```

To get the name value of the away team I have the following

```
SELECT * FROM fixtures JOIN teams ON fixtures.home_teamID = teams.TeamID 
JOIN teams ON fixtures.away_teamID = teams.TeamID
```

But this then returns a boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should join  the teams table two time  using two different alias

```
  SELECT fixtures.* a.* , b.*
  FROM fixtures 
  JOIN teams a ON fixtures.home_teamID = a.TeamID
  JOIN teams b ON fixtures.home_teamID = b.TeamID
```